# Data movement HDFS Vs Parallel file system Vs MPI

Tags: hadoop, filesystems, hdfs

I'm currently working on implementation of machine learning algorithms on MR-MPI (MapReduce on MPI). And i'm also trying to understand about other MapReduce frameworks especially Hadoop, so the following is my basic question (I'm new to MapReduce frameworks, i aplogize if my question dosen't make sense).

Question: Since MapReduce can be implemented on top of many things such as a parallel file system(GPFS), HDFS, MPI, e.t.c.,. After the map step there is a collate operation and then followed by a reduce operation. For a collate operation we need some data movement to happen across the nodes. In this regard i would like to know what is the difference in data movement mechanisms(between nodes) in HDFS Vs GPFS Vs MPI.

I appreciate if you provide me some good explanation and can give me some good references on each of these so i can get into further details.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MapReduce as a paradigm can bi implemented on many storage systems. Indeed Hadoop has so called DFS (Distributed file system) abstraction which enable integration of different storage system and run MapReduce over them. For example there are Amazon S3, Local file system, Opens Stack Swift and other integrations. 
In the same time HDFS integration has one special property - it reports to the MR engine (JobTracker, to be more specific) where data resides and it enable smart scheduling of Mapping in the way that data to be processed by each Mapper is usually collocated with the Mapper. 
As a result during Mapping phase data is not moved over network when MR run over HDFS.

To be more general can be stated that idea of Hadoop MR is to move code to data and not opposite, and it should be important criteria when evaluating any scalable MR implementation - does this system care that mappers process local data.

Comment: Can you please re-answer to my question. I made a small edit.

Answer (score 0):

The OP has mixed a couple of things - messaging and file system, so there are multiple ansewers.

Hadoop/MAPI is a WIP and you can find more details [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-2911).

Hadoop/GPFS is still [open](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-6330).

Hadoop/HDFS comes out of the box from [Apache Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/). For data transfer between the mappers and reducers HTTP is used, not sure why.